# read 4 char per thread in 1 transaction in cuda

Tags: cuda

I am learning CUDA recently. And I have a question about the memory transaction.
What I understand is, in each transaction, 32 consecutive threads (in the same block) can access a consecutive 128 bytes (32 single precision words) of memory concurrently, which is called a warp.
But in the example, each thread is always accessing the (4-bytes) word as 1 whole variable. So my question is, if my array in global memory is defined in type for char, then can all the 32 threads access this piece of memory, and read 4 consecutive char respectively in the same time?

So, for eaxmple, if I write the code:

```
__global__
void kernel(char *d_mask)
{
    extern __shared__ char s_tmp[];
    const unsigned int thId = threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int elementId = 4 * (threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);

    s_tmp[thId_x] = d_mask[elementId];
    s_tmp[1 + thId_x] = d_mask[elementId + 1];
    s_tmp[2 + thId_x] = d_mask[elementId + 2];
    s_tmp[3 + thId_x] = d_mask[elementId + 3];
    __syncthreads();

    /* calculation */
}
```

Then, will each thread read the 4 bytes concurrently? And if not, how can I manage to do it? should I use some API like memcpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a properly efficient read, it's necessary to combine the bytes being read into a single transaction; we generally can't do this by breaking things up across several lines of code.

To combine things into a single transaction, there are *vector types* which combine multiple elements into a single type.  As long as we [pay attention to proper alignment](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses), we can treat `char` or `unsigned char` arrays as arrays of e.g. `uchar4` which is a vector type that combines four characters into a single (32-bit) type.  You can find lots more goodies in the cuda header files `vector_types.h` and `vector_functions.h`.

Anyway, we could re-write your sample like this, to take advantage of a "vector load":

```
__global__
void kernel(char *d_mask)
{
    extern __shared__ char s_tmp[];
    const unsigned int thId = threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int elementId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    uchar4 *s_tmp_v  = reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(s_tmp);
    uchar4 *d_mask_v = reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(d_mask);
    s_tmp_v[thId] = d_mask_v[elementId];
    __syncthreads();

    /* calculation */
}
```